# Is there a way to find out if ServerRequest has a body?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I would like to check wether `ServerRequest` contains body.

Is there a way to find out that beforehand calling `bodyToMono` method?

Comment: by looking at the returned status code. According to the http standard if 200 you are obligated to look into the body, if 204 then there is no content.

Comment: I talk about request, not the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that clients do send corresponding headers, you can achieve it by checking the `content-length` header like this:

```
request.headers().contentLength().orElseGet(0) > 0
```

You can have it in the Handlers directly, or in a Filter as well

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.body(BodyExtracter)` method in Server request instance

To convert to a `Mono<Boolean>` which has `true` value if the body contains data, use

```
Mono<Boolean> bodyContains = request.body((serverHttpRequest, context) -> serverHttpRequest
    .getBody()
    .collectList()
    .map(List::isEmpty));
```

Comment: I will end up with a body that is already read and it will make it useless for further processing... That's why I want to find out a way to check if body exists before reading it....